# C++ Reading a file and it's individual characters to output to a table in the console

Tags: c++, file

I have a project due tomorrow that I've been working on for a while and I'm just plain stumped. This is exactly what's required of me:

Perform a few activities with a data file.  Create an input text file. 
Open an output file and the input file. 
On the screen, display your heading (see first program for what it should contain)
Echo all characters read from file to both the console and to the output file. (The output file will contain only a copy of the input file.)
On console, also display a “table” with headings showing how many digit, alpha, and other characters appear in the input file.
The ‘\t’ character is handy for tabbing between columns.
To console, display the total number of characters in the file.

This is just a basic programming course so we aren't using complicated stuff.

***UPDATE***

I've revamped things and taken them a step at a time, but I'm getting some weird errors in my if statements when I'm trying to rule out certain characters.

Here is what I have coded so far:

```
    string x;
    ifstream input ("input.txt");
    ofstream output ("output.txt");
        if(!input) cout<<"error"; //ensures opened file
    while (!input.eof()){
        input>>x;
        output<<x;
    }
    int digit=0;
    int alpha=0;
    int other=0;
    int count=0;

    input>>x;
    while (x!="-a"){

    if(x>='0'&&x<='9'){
        digit++;
        count++;
    }
    if((x>='a'&&x<='z')||(x>='A'&&x<='Z')){
        alpha++;
        count++;
    }
    if(x>='!'&&x<=')'){
        other++;
        count++;
    }

    x.erase(0,0);
    }
    cout<<"Your file has "<<digit<<" digits"<<endl;
    cout<<"Your file has "<<alpha<<" letters"<<endl;
    cout<<"Your file has "<<other<<" other characters"<<endl;

return 0;}
```

Comment: i think setw() is the best way out instead of using the \t

Comment: This is not an answer that shows you how to do the assignment, but in your sample, you will reset your counts each time you read from input, then increment it by 1. So at the end of the sample you have, "count" will only contain 1 and "sum" will output 0.

Answer (score 1):

The final solution required of you has some divisions: print the input on console; print the input to another file; print a table on console.

Start small and build step by step from there:

1. Read file, and as each character is read print it to console
2. If above is ok. Try printing each character to another file
3. If above is ok. Try counting each character type (if isDigit(c) and so on)
4. Then, print the counters on the console.
5. Merge the pieces of code, testing anything you feel is important.

The important thing for when you are learning to program and problem solving is to test. Don't be afraid to play with your code and print stuff to the screen. Try to do some table tests on paper as well, as if you were the computer executing your code.

Comment: would you mind looking at my updated code? The error I'm getting says "no match for 'operator'..." and it will tell me which operator. I don't really understand this error and can't finish without fixing it.

Comment: @ZacharyKnapp I looked into your code and here is a couple notes: since you need to read one character at a time, it is better to use 'char x' instead of 'string x'. Else it will try to read a whole word by default.
Another thing, once you do 'while(!input.eof()) {input >> x}', it will go through your whole file and stop at EOF sign. If you try doing it again (as you do on the second while), it will not have anything else to read. You would have to use the function 'seek', to go back to the beginning.

Comment: I think you error is due to the string to char comparisson. A string is compared with double quotes (""), and char with single quotes('').
Another tip: if it does not detect and output line breaks ('\n'), try reading a whole line (input.getline()) into a string, and then iterate over it, counting characters and printing to the screen/file. This way, it will preserve the line breaks.